# Frequent crashes with Deezer Android SDK

Tags: android, deezer

Here's a typical crash:

```
13:37:36.166  23654-23669/com.soundrop.android V/dalvikvm﹕ +++ calling dlsym(Java_com_deezer_sdk_player_impl_RealPlayerImpl_cStop)
13:37:36.166  23654-23669/com.soundrop.android V/dalvikvm﹕ Found 'Java_com_deezer_sdk_player_impl_RealPlayerImpl_cStop' with dlsym
13:37:36.178  23654-23901/com.soundrop.android A/libc﹕ Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x6174658f (code=1), thread 23901 (Thread-369)
13:37:36.278      103-103/? I/DEBUG﹕ *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
13:37:36.278      103-103/? I/DEBUG﹕ Build fingerprint: 'generic/vbox86p/vbox86p:4.2.2/JDQ39E/eng.buildbot.20130923.154959:userdebug/test-keys'
13:37:36.278      103-103/? I/DEBUG﹕ Revision: '0'
13:37:36.278      103-103/? I/DEBUG﹕ pid: 23654, tid: 23901, name: Thread-369  >>> com.soundrop.android <<<
13:37:36.278      103-103/? I/DEBUG﹕ signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 6174658f
13:37:36.454      103-103/? I/DEBUG﹕ eax b7536e10  ebx b759dff4  ecx 61746567  edx 00000003
13:37:36.454      103-103/? I/DEBUG﹕ esi 61746567  edi 22030020
13:37:36.454      103-103/? I/DEBUG﹕ xcs 00000073  xds 0000007b  xes 0000007b  xfs 00000043  xss 0000007b
13:37:36.454      103-103/? I/DEBUG﹕ eip b7536e2f  ebp 967188f4  esp 967188ac  flags 00010292
13:37:36.454      103-103/? I/DEBUG﹕ backtrace:
13:37:36.454      103-103/? I/DEBUG﹕ #00  pc 00031e2f  /system/lib/libc.so (ftell+31)
13:37:36.454      103-103/? I/DEBUG﹕ #01  pc 0012fc73  <unknown>
13:37:36.454      103-103/? I/DEBUG﹕ #02  pc 0002e020  <unknown>
13:37:36.454      103-103/? I/DEBUG﹕ #03  pc 0002e020  <unknown>
13:37:36.454      103-103/? I/DEBUG﹕ #04  pc 0002e020  <unknown>
13:37:36.454      103-103/? I/DEBUG﹕ #05  pc 0002e020  <unknown>
13:37:36.454      103-103/? I/DEBUG﹕ #06  pc 0002e020  <unknown>
13:37:36.454      103-103/? I/DEBUG﹕ #07  pc 0002e020  <unknown>
13:37:36.454      103-103/? I/DEBUG﹕ #08  pc 0002e020  <unknown>
13:37:36.454      103-103/? I/DEBUG﹕ #09  pc 0002e020  <unknown>
13:37:36.454      103-103/? I/DEBUG﹕ #10  pc 0002e020  <unknown>
13:37:36.454      103-103/? I/DEBUG﹕ #11  pc 0002e020  <unknown>
13:37:36.454      103-103/? I/DEBUG﹕ #12  pc 0002e020  <unknown>
13:37:36.454      103-103/? I/DEBUG﹕ #13  pc 0002e020  <unknown>
13:37:36.454      103-103/? I/DEBUG﹕ #14  pc 0002e020  <unknown>
13:37:36.454      103-103/? I/DEBUG﹕ #15  pc 0002e020  <unknown>
13:37:36.454      103-103/? I/DEBUG﹕ #16  pc 0002e020  <unknown>
13:37:36.454      103-103/? I/DEBUG﹕ #17  pc 0002e020  <unknown>
13:37:36.454      103-103/? I/DEBUG﹕ #18  pc 0002e020  <unknown>
13:37:36.454      103-103/? I/DEBUG﹕ #19  pc 0002e020  <unknown>
13:37:36.454      103-103/? I/DEBUG﹕ #20  pc 0002e020  <unknown>
13:37:36.454      103-103/? I/DEBUG﹕ #21  pc 0002e020  <unknown>
13:37:36.454      103-103/? I/DEBUG﹕ #22  pc 0002e020  <unknown>
13:37:36.454      103-103/? I/DEBUG﹕ #23  pc 0002e020  <unknown>
13:37:36.454      103-103/? I/DEBUG﹕ #24  pc 0002e020  <unknown>
13:37:36.454      103-103/? I/DEBUG﹕ #25  pc 0002e020  <unknown>
13:37:36.454      103-103/? I/DEBUG﹕ #26  pc 0002e020  <unknown>
13:37:36.454      103-103/? I/DEBUG﹕ #27  pc 0002e020  <unknown>
13:37:36.454      103-103/? I/DEBUG﹕ #28  pc 0002e020  <unknown>
13:37:36.454      103-103/? I/DEBUG﹕ #29  pc 0002e020  <unknown>
13:37:36.454      103-103/? I/DEBUG﹕ #30  pc 0002e020  <unknown>
13:37:36.454      103-103/? I/DEBUG﹕ #31  pc 0002e020  <unknown>
13:37:36.454      103-103/? I/DEBUG﹕ stack:
13:37:36.454      103-103/? I/DEBUG﹕ 9671886c  00000000
13:37:36.454      103-103/? I/DEBUG﹕ 96718870  00000000
13:37:36.454      103-103/? I/DEBUG﹕ 96718874  00000000
13:37:36.454      103-103/? I/DEBUG﹕ 96718878  00000000
13:37:36.454      103-103/? I/DEBUG﹕ 9671887c  00000000
13:37:36.454      103-103/? I/DEBUG﹕ 96718880  00000000
13:37:36.454      103-103/? I/DEBUG﹕ 96718884  00000000
13:37:36.454      103-103/? I/DEBUG﹕ 96718888  00000000
13:37:36.454      103-103/? I/DEBUG﹕ 9671888c  00000000
13:37:36.454      103-103/? I/DEBUG﹕ 96718890  00000000
13:37:36.454      103-103/? I/DEBUG﹕ 96718894  00000000
13:37:36.454      103-103/? I/DEBUG﹕ 96718898  00000000
13:37:36.454      103-103/? I/DEBUG﹕ 9671889c  00000000
13:37:36.454      103-103/? I/DEBUG﹕ 967188a0  00000000
13:37:36.454      103-103/? I/DEBUG﹕ 967188a4  00000000
13:37:36.454      103-103/? I/DEBUG﹕ 967188a8  00000000
13:37:36.454      103-103/? I/DEBUG﹕ #00  967188ac  00000000
13:37:36.454      103-103/? I/DEBUG﹕ 967188b0  96b50ba0  /system/lib/libhoudini.so
13:37:36.454      103-103/? I/DEBUG﹕ 967188b4  380078d7  /data/app-lib/com.soundrop.android-2/libdeezer.so
13:37:36.454      103-103/? I/DEBUG﹕ 967188b8  00000000
13:37:36.454      103-103/? I/DEBUG﹕ 967188bc  967188dc  [stack:23901]
13:37:36.454      103-103/? I/DEBUG﹕ 967188c0  96b50d4d  /system/lib/libhoudini.so
13:37:36.454      103-103/? I/DEBUG﹕ 967188c4  200d64f0
13:37:36.454      103-103/? I/DEBUG﹕ 967188c8  00000000
13:37:36.454      103-103/? I/DEBUG﹕ 967188cc  00000000
13:37:36.454      103-103/? I/DEBUG﹕ 967188d0  61746567
13:37:36.454      103-103/? I/DEBUG﹕ 967188d4  22030020
13:37:36.454      103-103/? I/DEBUG﹕ 967188d8  96bc3f5b  /system/lib/libhoudini.so
13:37:36.454      103-103/? I/DEBUG﹕ 967188dc  61746567
13:37:36.454      103-103/? I/DEBUG﹕ 967188e0  96b4f04f  /system/lib/libhoudini.so
13:37:36.454      103-103/? I/DEBUG﹕ 967188e4  00000000
13:37:36.454      103-103/? I/DEBUG﹕ 967188e8  00000000
13:37:36.454      103-103/? I/DEBUG﹕ ........  ........
13:37:36.458      103-103/? I/DEBUG﹕ #01  967188fc  000007c5
13:37:36.458      103-103/? I/DEBUG﹕ ........  ........
13:37:36.458      103-103/? I/DEBUG﹕ #02  22030008  220301c0
13:37:36.458      103-103/? I/DEBUG﹕ ........  ........
13:37:36.458      103-103/? I/DEBUG﹕ memory map around fault addr 6174658f:
13:37:36.458      103-103/? I/DEBUG﹕ 3861f000-40000000
13:37:36.458      103-103/? I/DEBUG﹕ (no map for address)
13:37:36.458      103-103/? I/DEBUG﹕ 95e25000-95e26000
```

Is this a known issue or are there any pitfalls that may lead to this? I've made sure all interaction with the Deezer player happens from one single background thread, and my callbacks from Deezer do nothing but post a message to this background thread.

Comment: I noticed some calls to /system/lib/libhoudini.so in the stack trace, which makes me think this happens in an Android Emulator. Am I right ? Are you having this problem on real  device too ?

Comment: That's correct (I'm using [Genymotion](http://www.genymotion.com/) while developing). Don't know yet if it happens on a real device, but will let you know after some more testing. It seems to happen between tracks, and I suspect it's a race condition where a track is ending and the app calls stop() concurrently.

Comment: I'll wait for your feedback on a real device, as the stack trace itself (#.. pc 00005520) never implies libdeeezer.so directly and only  /system/lib/libc.so /system/lib/libhoudini.so. My guess is that the emulator adds some operation in libc.so (standard c library) wihch leads to this crash

Comment: True. I can see libdeezer.so in the stack trace though, but I guess it's hard to tell for sure what's going on.  I've been testing a while on my phone but haven't been able to reproduce this issue yet. I'll keep you posted.

Comment: How much RAM  / Heap size did you set on your emulator ? those segfaults might occur because you don't have enough memory (I just had the same problem with an automated AVD with only 96 Mb of RAM)

Comment: My emulator has 2 GB of RAM (Genymotion's Galaxy S4 profile, which configures the VM with specs matching the S4 as close as possible).